# Controller and Directive requesting isolated scope on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a problem when trying adding ng-intro-options attribute on the  element

**The Code**

```
var App = angular.module('MyApp', ['infinite-scroll', 'angular-intro']);
App.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.IntroOptions = {}
}]);
```

**and the HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyController" ng-intro-options="IntroOptions">
```

But AngularJS is throwing error mentioning the URL:

```
http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir
```

The error is thrown as soon as I add the attr for angular-intro on the body tag. I'm using angular 1.3.5

Comment: What is `ngIntroOptions` directive?

Comment: use development version of angular (not min) for more verbose errors and stack trace output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is issue with the latest version of angular, Which is not stable version.

That issue is even reproducible with angular 1.3.0

It is working as expected with `https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/angular.js` which is stable release.

[**angular 1.2.27 Fidlle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGT7DmEBNhWLDV15Grkp?p=preview) working as expected.

[**angular 1.3.0 and above Fidlle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IqwV8aWA0IqMjpeMI1QY?p=preview) giving some error like you are getting. Check console

Switch back to stable version will solve your issue.

Hopefully it will helpful to you.